# Ansible Register Instances and Create ELBs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-elb

I'm trying to create an ansible playbook to dynamically find any instances matching AWS tags, create an ELB and then add the instances to it.  So far I have been successful in creating these for one set of tags and one ELB at a time.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to have this run for any number of tags without specifying my variables `function` and `release` up front.

For example, the `function` and `release` variables would be defined in a vars file something like this.

```
function:
  - api
  - webapp
  - mysql
release:
  - prod
  - stage
  - dev
```

My playbook looks like this.  I'm struggling to find a way to loop the entire playbook through a variable list.  If I add a `with_items` to the first task it loops that entire task before moving onto the next one which does not accomplish what I want.

```
- ec2_remote_facts:
    filters:
      instance-state-name: running
      "tag:Function": "{{ function }}"
      "tag:Release": "{{ release }}"
    region: us-east-1
  register: ec2instance

- local_action:
    module: ec2_elb_lb
    name: "{{ function }}-{{ release }}"
    state: present
    instance_ids: "{{ item.id }}"
    purge_instance_ids: true
    region: us-east-1
    subnets:
      - subnet-1
      - subnet-2
    listeners:
      - protocol: https
        load_balancer_port: 443
        instance_port: 80
        ssl_certificate_id: "{{ ssl_certificate_id }}"
    health_check:
        ping_protocol: http
        ping_port: 80
        ping_path: "/status"
        response_timeout: 3
        interval: 5
        unhealthy_threshold: 2
        healthy_threshold: 2
    access_logs:
        interval: 5
        s3_location: "{{ function }}-{{ release }}-elb"
        s3_prefix: "logs"
  with_items: ec2instance.instances
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing I can think of is parameterized include.
Make a list of tasks for a single shot, e.g. `elb_from_tagged_instances.yml`.
Then make `main.yml` with `include` in a loop:

```
- include: elb_from_tagged_instances.yml function={{item[0]}} release={{item[1]}}
  with_together:
      - "{{function}}"
      - "{{release}}"
```

And if you don't need to somehow cross-intersect functions/releases, I'd replace two lists function/release with one list of dict and iterate over it.

**UPDATE:** Example for nested loop to get 9 pairs:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    functions:
      - api
      - webapp
      - mysql
    releases:
      - prod
      - stage
      - dev
  tasks:
    - include: include_z1.yml function="{{item[0]}}" release="{{item[1]}}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{functions}}"
        - "{{releases}}"
```

Also note, that you should use different names for list and parameter (`function` and `functions` (plural) in my example) to avoid recursive templating.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This seems to work fine for getting the loop to work but I've been unable to make it work with more than 1 set of {{function}} and {{release}} simultaneously.  What happens is the {{function}}-{{release}} comes out as one large value like "msg": "[u'api', u'webapp', u'mysql']-[u'prod', u'stage', u'dev']"  Also, i hope to have.  api-prod, api-stage, api-dev, webapp-prod, webapp-stage...etc.   Any way you can think to do that?

Comment: @tweeks200 very strange thing indeed... I've updated my answer with code I've tested.

Comment: @tweeks200 found a bug why my templated loops didn't work, updated the answer again :) different names for parameter of include (`function`) and array (`functions`) is a key!

Comment: thanks! had to loop control but works like a charm!  `- include: aws_provision_elb.yml function="{{outer_item[0]}}" release="{{outer_item[1]}}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ functions }}"
        - "{{ releases }}"
      loop_control:
          loop_var: outer_item`